# "Cannot Convert Lambda Expression to Delegate type" Error in RavenDB query

Tags: linq, ravendb

I have a RavenDb document that looks like this:

```
{
  "ParentId": null,
  "Order": 10,
  "Url": "/sandbox",
  "Rows": 
  [
    {
      "InstanceId": "2771a0d7-7f3f-4854-a3ba-27f25f88a45e",
      "CSSClass": null,
      "Columns": 
      [
        {
          "InstanceId": "b91495f5-b770-4da7-8073-ad3bd8221ca8",
          "CSSClass": null,
          "Span": 3,
          "CMSModuleInstanceSettings": 
          [
            {
              "$type": "ModuleHTML.Models.ModuleHTMLInstanceSettings, ModuleHTML",
              "IsActive": false,
              "ShowAuthor": false,
              "ShowDate": false,
              "ShowCommentsCount": false,
              "ShowLast2Comments": false,
              "CMSModuleInstanceId": 417,
              "ContainerClass": "default",
              "ModuleType": "ModuleHTML",
              "DisplayType": "Summary"
            },
            {
              "$type": "ModuleHTML.Models.ModuleHTMLInstanceSettings, ModuleHTML",
              "IsActive": false,
              "ShowAuthor": false,
              "ShowDate": false,
              "ShowCommentsCount": false,
              "ShowLast2Comments": false,
              "CMSModuleInstanceId": 545,
              "ContainerClass": "default",
              "ModuleType": "ModuleHTML",
              "DisplayType": "Summary"
            }
          ],
          "Id": 0,
          "Name": null,
          "CreatedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000",
          "CreatedBy": 0,
          "LastModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000",
          "LastModifiedBy": 0
        },
        ...
      ],
      ...
    },
    ...
  ],
  ...
}
```

and I want to retrieve the page document and include the rows, columns and then only the CMSModuleInstanceSettings that are active.

I have tried:

```
var page = documentSession.Query<CMSPage>()
             .SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == pageId)
             .Rows
             .Any(x => x.Columns
               .Any(z => z.CMSModuleInstanceSettings
                 .Where(m => m.IsActive == true)));
```

but it returns :

```
Error 1 Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type
'System.Func<CMS.Models.CMSColumn,bool>' because some of 
the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible 
to the delegate return type
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You are aware that you are actually doing a query then an in memory filter, right?

Split it like this:

```
  var page = documentSession.Query<CMSPage>()
         .SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == pageId);
```

And:

```
  var rows =             page.Rows
         .Any(x => x.Columns
           .Any(z => z.CMSModuleInstanceSettings
             .Where(m => m.IsActive == true)));
```

Where do you get the error now?

Comment: Hi Ayende, thanks for your response. BTW - Raven is awesome! 

Error 1 Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func<CMS.Models.CMSColumn,bool>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type 

and second error:
Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CMS.Models.CMSModuleInstanceSetting>' to 'bool'

Comment: Ultimately i want to still return a page object but have the child objects filtered. In other words I don't want a Row collection. Is that possible?

Comment: If you actually want the child objects, then Any() is not what you want. I'm guessing you're new to LINQ. You probably want .Where() the whole way down. I would project the original page into a clone that has the subcollections filtered.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is a better way, but this is what I ended up doing....

```
var page = documentSession.Load<CMSPage>(pageId);

foreach (var row in page.Rows)
            {
                foreach (var column in row.Columns)
                {
                    var settings = column.CMSModuleInstanceSettings.ToList();
                    settings.ForEach(x => settings.Remove(x));
                    column.CMSModuleInstanceSettings = settings;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Be careful about modifying your original document and its sub-objects, because if you save back to Raven you will be saving those changes to the database.